# CSS pseudo before automatic numbering - indentation

Tags: css

I would like to make the text of the first line indented like the second line (50px). Any way to do it? Many thanks!

```css
body {
 counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h1 {
 counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h2 {
 padding-left: 50px;
 text-indent: -50px;
}
h2:before {
 content: counter(h2counter) ".";
 counter-increment: h2counter;
 left: 0;
 width: 50px;
 text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Take bus 1627 running from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport to Zhongli Service Area. Get off at Zhongli Service Area for the transfer to the next bus. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=37" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=2986" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus</a>; <a href="http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/Buses/#e0871f13-0119-445f-8a41-f9a6913cc00e" target="_blank">Airport transportation guide</a></h2>
<h2>Take bus 1618 running from Taipei Bus Station to Chiayi Bus Station. Some buses do not stop at Linkou and Zhonggang Bus Station, but this does not matter to passengers going to Chiayi. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=23" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=4321" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 1</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=9237" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 2</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h2 {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
h2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: counter(h2counter)".";
  counter-increment: h2counter;
  /* Adjust 'left' value as required */
  left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Take bus 1627 running from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport to Zhongli Service Area. Get off at Zhongli Service Area for the transfer to the next bus. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=37" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=2986" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus</a>; <a href="http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/Buses/#e0871f13-0119-445f-8a41-f9a6913cc00e" target="_blank">Airport transportation guide</a></h2>
<h2>Take bus 1618 running from Taipei Bus Station to Chiayi Bus Station. Some buses do not stop at Linkou and Zhonggang Bus Station, but this does not matter to passengers going to Chiayi. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=23" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=4321" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 1</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=9237" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 2</a></h2>
```

Comment: @Sen : You can up vote all the helpful answers here. Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you mean like this, but I'm not sure.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2counter;
}
h2 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  text-indent: -50px;
}
h2::before {
  content: counter(h2counter)".";
  counter-increment: h2counter;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
/* Clear fix */
h2::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Take bus 1627 running from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport to Zhongli Service Area. Get off at Zhongli Service Area for the transfer to the next bus. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=37" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=2986" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus</a>; <a href="http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/Buses/#e0871f13-0119-445f-8a41-f9a6913cc00e" target="_blank">Airport transportation guide</a></h2>
<h2>Take bus 1618 running from Taipei Bus Station to Chiayi Bus Station. Some buses do not stop at Linkou and Zhonggang Bus Station, but this does not matter to passengers going to Chiayi. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=23" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=4321" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 1</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=9237" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 2</a></h2>
```

Comment: It's close but the numbering plus 30px margin-right are not exactly the same as in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `text-indent: -50px;` from CSS class `h2`.

```css
h2 {
 padding-left: 50px;
}
h2:before {
 content: counter(h2counter) ".";
 counter-increment: h2counter;
 left: 0;
 text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Take bus 1627 running from Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport to Zhongli Service Area. Get off at Zhongli Service Area for the transfer to the next bus. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=37" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=2986" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus</a>; <a href="http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english/Buses/#e0871f13-0119-445f-8a41-f9a6913cc00e" target="_blank">Airport transportation guide</a></h2>
<h2>Take bus 1618 running from Taipei Bus Station to Chiayi Bus Station. Some buses do not stop at Linkou and Zhonggang Bus Station, but this does not matter to passengers going to Chiayi. More bus details: <a href="http://www.ubus.com.tw/html/line/show.php?num=23" target="_blank">Ubus</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=4321" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 1</a>; <a href="http://www.taiwanbus.tw/information.aspx?Lang=En&Line=9237" target="_blank">Taiwan Bus 2</a></h2>
```